# 2D Screen Overlay in Unity for MRTKv2/Hololens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I want to make a 2D Screen Overlay with Unity on Hololens2.
I created a Unity Canvas set to "Screen Space - Camera" Render Mode and tried to add the Camera provided by the MRTK as the Render Camera. This resulted in the following error:

```
TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.ConvertValues (System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] pinfo, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) (at <567df3e0919241ba98db88bec4c6696f>:0)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <567df3e0919241ba98db88bec4c6696f>:0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at <567df3e0919241ba98db88bec4c6696f>:0)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityCanvasInspector.AllRootCanvases () (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/InputSystem/Editor/MixedRealityCanvasInspector.cs:206)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityCanvasInspector.OnInspectorGUI () (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/InputSystem/Editor/MixedRealityCanvasInspector.cs:334)
UnityEditor.UIElements.InspectorElement+<CreateIMGUIInspectorFromEditor>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorElement.cs:501)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)
```

I don't know if this is a bug or if this is intended. My current workaround would be to calculate the worldspace position and dimensions of the overlay in front of the camera.

Is there any simple way to make the Hololens2 render a 2D Screen Overlay?

Comment: ... you don't want to do that. A 2D screen space overlay would be at camera distance `0` so there would be no chance for anyone to focus on that content. Also afaik Screenspaceoverlay is not rendered anyway as soon as `VR support` is enabled. What is your actual goal with such a Canvas?

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for your comment. I am aware, that screen space overlay will not be rendered when VR support is enabled. Therefore I want to use sceen space camera, as described above. My goal is to render a 2D HUD like the one in [this tutorial](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/03/06/building-terminator-vision-hud-hololens/).

Comment: For MR devices you will always have to use a `Worldspace` canvas! You can use the MRTK's `SolverHandler` + `Orbital` (see [MRTK - Solvers](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html))   in order to always make it float in front of the camera